# How to set default user association within Cuba-Platform / Studio

Tags: cuba-platform

If anyone has a code sample of recording the user id of the currently logged in user to a record when it is created it would be greatly appreciated.

The scenario is this:

I have extended the user entity to include an association to an Organization entity.

In the main entity in question, I have created two association attributes:
systemUser and organization.

The idea is to set the user id (not username) and the organization id of the user creating the record to the when they create a new item.

I seem to have hit a brick wall.

Any sample of what that code might look like would be appreciated.

Comment: A [mcve] might help us understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UserSessionSource` bean to get currently logged in User and their Id:

```
@Inject
protected UserSessionSource userSessionSource;

User user = userSessionSource.getUserSession().getUser();
UUID userId = user.getId();
```

This way you can obtain id and then set it to your entity. In order to do it on new entity creation you could use Entity Listeners https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.9/entity_listeners.html